# Setup log file name based on MDC via XML config file

Tags: logback

What I exactly need to do is to have **different log files for different users**.
I know how to do it directly in Java.

What I want to have opportunity to setup this via `logback.xml` configuration file.
Like this:

```xml
 <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <fileNamePattern>logFile.%X{USER}.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</fileNamePattern>
    </rollingPolicy>
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %logger - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>
```

Note that writting **%X{USER}** is not correct, it's just an example what I want to do.

**So**:Is it possible to do setup log file name in `logback.xml` configuration file?

---

I'm using Logback 1.0.7

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use SiftingAppender, please refer to : http://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html#SiftingAppender

Comment: Please note, that you should be careful with it in case when count of different file name values is unpredictable. Because each sub-logger would be kept in the cache (can cause OOM). Also each file-based logger has file descriptors (may lead to out of file descriptors for a runtime).But if the count of different values is not that much (say, less than 100), it's fine.